# Could not deduce (Eq a) from the context (...)

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I'm new to Haskell. I wrote this code:

```
deleteDuplicates :: [a] -> [a]
deleteDuplicates [] = []
deleteDuplicates (x:xs)
        | x == (head xs)        = x : (deleteDuplicates (tail xs))
        | otherwise             = x : (head xs) : (deleteDuplicates (tail xs))
```

What does this error mean and why did it occur? Am I accidentally comparing two different types somehow?

```
set2.hs:10:3:
    Could not deduce (Eq a) from the context ()
      arising from a use of `==' at set2.hs:10:3-16
    Possible fix:
      add (Eq a) to the context of
        the type signature for `deleteDuplicates'
    In the expression: x == (head xs)
        In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                 the definition of `deleteDuplicates':
          x == (head xs)
    In the definition of `deleteDuplicates':
        deleteDuplicates (x : xs)
                           | x == (head xs) = x : (deleteDuplicates (tail xs))
                           | otherwise = x : (head xs) : (deleteDuplicates (tail xs))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your type signature is wrong:

```
deleteDuplicates :: [a] -> [a]
```

That says your function can work on lists of any type, `a`, but that isn't true!  You later call:

```
x == (head xs)
```

So you must be able to compare your type for equality.  Meaning the signature must be:

```
deleteDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

At times like this it's good to remove your explicit type signature, load the function in GHCi and discover what type the interpreter thinks it should have (via `:t deleteDuplicates`).

**More Bugs**

Additionally, your use of `head` there is a bad idea.  `head` is a partial function and will fail when `xs == []`.  I suggest you expand the pattern match:

```
deleteDuplicates (x1:x2:xs)
    | x1 == x2 = ...
    | otherwise = x1 : deleteDuplicates (x2:xs)
```

Also notice the fix to the `otherwise` case.  You were skipping over x2, but what if x2 matched the next element in the list?  Something like `[1,2,2,3]` would have discovered `1 /= 2` and then the recursion would have gotten the list `[2,3]` - oops!

Comment: You're completely right about something like `[1, 2, 2, 3]` failing to produce a list with all duplicates removed. My bad. The `Eq a =>` thing is new to me... so the only thing that does is enforce that elements of type `a` should be comparable?

Comment: Pieter: Basically, yes.  It is a "typeclass constraint".  The function `==` is declared in the `Eq` typeclass, so it can only be used on instances of Eq.

Comment: @Pieter: comparable for equality, yes.  `Eq a =>` says that `a` must be an instance of the type class `Eq`.  A type class specifies an interface which the instance implements.  The `Eq` class provides two functions, `(==)` and `(/=)`, both with type `a -> a -> Bool`.  Other type classes will provide other functions, for example `Ord` provides less-than, greater-than, and similar ordering tests.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that from the type signature alone it can't work out if `a` is an instanceof `Eq`.

```
deleteDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

You need to tell the compiler that `a` is an instance of the [Eq](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aEq) type class by mentioning it in the signature.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
x == (head xs)
```

requires `==` to be defined on the members of `xs`, which means `a` must be an instance of the typeclass `Eq`. Change your function's type signature to

```
deleteDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```